# Stop local notification sound in Android

Tags: android

I have implemented local notification with sound. It's working properly but  when I clear local notification the custom sound what I am playing should stop.

```
Uri uri = null;
String[] split = content.split("-");
Intent intents = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intents, 0);
//getting audio from raw folder
uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.beep);

//plays audio infinite times until user clicks or clear notification
try 
{
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.start();

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(split[0])
        .setContentText(device_name + split[1]).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.hi_notification)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .build();

    noti.sound = uri;
    noti.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
}
catch (IllegalStateException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I think just add   
.setAutoCancel(true), it will cancel the notification and stops the sound too

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried this its not stoping.

Answer (score 0):

Set the notification sound to be INSISTENT.

1.Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND:used to play sound.

2.Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT:this flag is makes your sound to ring continuously until you have done few operations on notification ie, either you drag the bar or you click the bar.

3.Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL:this flag is used to automatically cancel the notification after you have seen it

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon).setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
            .addAction(R.drawable.alarm_off, getString(R.string.dismiss), pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSound(Uri.parse(path));

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(WAKE_UP_ALARM_ID, notification)
```

Comment: Thank you very much its stoping when i clear notification but onclick its not stoping.How can I do this.

Comment: Try this code and set your flag               notification.flags=Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT|Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS|Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

Comment: Thank you but it dint work.Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT |Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL this worked for me.

Comment: I actually dont want vibrate so I used noti.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS |~ Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE.after using this default mobile audio and app audio both are triggering same time.How can i stop default audio sound and custom audio sound.

Comment: could  you please provide the full code of the class